# Matlab - if exists a faster way to assign values to big matrix?

Tags: performance, algorithm, matlab, for-loop

I am a new student learning to use Matlab.
Could anyone please tell me is there a faster way possibly without loops:
to assign for each row only two values 1, -1 into different positions of a big sparse matrix.

My code to build a bimatrix or bibimatrix for the MILP problem of condition :

f^k_{ij} <= y_{ij} for every arc (i,j) and all k ~=r; in a multi-commodity flow model.

Naive approach:

bimatrix=[];

% create each row and then add to bimatrix

```
newrow4= zeros(1,n*(n+1)^2);

for k=1:n

    for i=0:n
        for j=1: n
            if j~=i          
                %change value of some positions to -1 and 1 
                newrow4(i*n^2+(j-1)*n+k)=1;
                newrow4((n+1)*n^2+i*n+j)=-1;
                % add to bimatrix
                bimatrix=[bimatrix; newrow4];
                % change newrow4 back to zeros row.
                newrow4(i*n^2+(j-1)*n+k)=0;
                newrow4((n+1)*n^2+i*n+j)=0;
            end
        end
    end
end
```

OR:

% Generate the big sparse matrix first.

```
bibimatrix=zeros(n^3 ,n*(n+1)^2);

t=1;

for k=1:n

    for i=0:n
        for j=1: n
            if j~=i           
                %Change 2 positions in each row to -1 and 1 in each row.
                bibimatrix(t,i*n^2+(j-1)*n+k)=1;
                bibimatrix(t,(n+1)*n^2+i*n+j)=-1;
                t=t+1
            end
        end
    end
end
```

With these above code in Matlab, the time to generate this matrix, with n~12, is more than 3s. I need to generate a larger matrix in less time.

Thank you.

Comment: What the logic with that indexing ?

Comment: Your two loops do not result in the same output. You also say, that it only consists of 1 and -1, but most of the entries are 0. Please check if the code is right and explain what your matrix should look like.

Comment: Always, always pre-allocate memory for your matrices!

Comment: @RobertP. He did it. Check first line. He creates zeros matrix.

Comment: @AlexandreBizeau, I beg to differ. You are right about `bibimatrix`, but I can't see where `bimatrix` is initialized...

Comment: Sorry, cause I first post without comment. I modify it so bimatrix== bibimatrix now.

Comment: Like @RobertP. point, `bimatrix=[];` and `bimatrix=[bimatrix; newrow4];` never use thing like that (except if you don't care about performance). But I don't understand what your code is suppose to do. So try to explain what this should do or look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suggestion: Use [sparse](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) matrices.

You should be able to create two vectors containing the column number where you want your `+1` and `-1` in each row. Let's call these two vectors `vec_1` and `vec_2`. You should be able to do this without loops (if not, I still think the procedure below will be faster).

Let the size of your matrix be `(max_row X max_col)`. Then you can create your matrix like this:

```
bibimatrix = sparse(1:max_row,vec_1,1,max_row,max_col);
bibimatrix = bibimatrix + sparse(1:max_row, vec_2,-1,max_row,max_col)
```

If you want to see the entire matrix (which you don't, since it's huge) you can write: `full(bibimatrix)`.

EDIT:
You may also do it this way:

```
col_vec = [vec_1, vec_2];
row_vec = [1:max_row, 1:max_row];
s = [ones(1,max_row), -1*ones(1,max_row)];
bibimatrix = sparse(row_vec, col_vec, s, max_row, max_col)
```

Disclaimer: I don't have MATLAB available, so it might not be error-free.

Comment: Thanks. I am thinking of the similar way with the command sub2ind. Don't know which one from sparse or sub2ind will be faster?

Comment: @VNese, I would put all my money on sparse. Your matrices are also very big, so you will save a lot of memory using sparse techniques, since only the non-zero elements are stored.